# WebP image support for ImageIO .getImageReadersByMIMEType in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javax.imageio

I tried the following piece of code.I included libwebp-imageIO.so into native library path as suggested in [the WebP-imageio docs](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio).

```
ImageInputStream imageInputStream = new FileImageInputStream(imagefile);

Iterator<ImageReader> ite  = ImageIO.getImageReadersByMIMEType("image/webp");
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;

while (ite.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader imageReader = ite.next();
    imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream);
    bufferedImage = imageReader.read(0);
}
```

In this piece of code, the bufferedimage is null and throws the following exception for webp format images.I believe the ImageIO supports webP format images,then why cannot it read a file of webp images.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebP
    at com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPReader.readHeader(WebPReader.java:58)
    at com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPReader.read(WebPReader.java:147)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:939)
```

Comment: Can you reformat this to a small, compilable unit that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The exception you see is usually preceded with an `ExceptionInInitializerError` which will tell you why the `WebP` class could not be initialized. If you find it, post that stack trace too. May be a problem opening the native library.